# Filter Form Based on 2 Values in the Same Text Box

Tags: ms-access, filter

I have a text box called `[Status]` that a user can populate using a combo box.

I want to filter my form based on two potential values in the text box value - `Pipeline` or `Forecast`.  The filter is activated by a checkbox.  Click check box get records where the `[Status]` is either `Pipeline` or `Forecast`.

The checkbox code is easy enough.  I am having trouble getting Access to filter on two possible values in the same text box.

I've tried

```
Private Sub checkboxFilterActive_AfterUpdate()   

If checkboxFilterActive = True Then

   Me.Filter = "[status]='Pipeline'" And "[status]='forecast'" 'Filter Code
   
   Me.FilterOn = True
Else
    Me.FilterOn = False
End If

End Sub
```

This throws a type mismatch error.

I've tried

```
Private Sub checkboxFilterActive_AfterUpdate()

Dim strFilter As String

strFilter = "[Status]='Forecast'" & "'AND [Status] = 'Pipeline'"

If checkboxFilterActive = True Then

    DoCmd.ApplyFilter , strFilter
 
  
Else
    DoCmd.ShowAllRecords
End If

End Sub
```

This throws a Syntax error (missing operator) query expression error.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use OR instead of AND. Also, OR operator is literal text and needs to be within quote marks to build criteria string.

`Me.Filter = "[status]='Pipeline' OR [status]='forecast'" 'Filter Code`

Comment: Thanks again @June7.  Really appreciate your help.